# How to retrieve flat binary from an executable file in C

Tags: c++, c, elf, objcopy, bfd

How to retrieve a block of binary from .text section in an executable?

I know objcopy can help by using:

```
objcopy --only-section=.text --output-target binary a.out a.out.bin
```

But it would be much better if I can realize the same goal within a function call using BFD library. Is there any way to call objcopy using function calls?

Comment: What is your definition of "flat binary", that is, what are you going to use it for?

Comment: I'm sure this is possible with BFD, but in my quick look at it, I don't think it's a "simple" task. What objcopy does is to copy the section content out.

Comment: A flat binary is a binary file without ELF headers. I'm going to perform some static analysis on the binary, which only requires the binary block from .text section.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for function in binutils / bfd libs. You can find doc at http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/binutils/bfd_toc.html and I think the function you are looking for is:

```
boolean bfd_get_section_contents (bfd *abfd, asection *section,
    PTR location, file_ptr offset,
    bfd_size_type count);
```

whose doc can be find at http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/binutils/bfd_57.html